# I was trying to create A collapsing Sidebar, but it goes invisible as soon as I create another section below my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

**The main problem im facing right now is the sidebar fading away when i try to click on the hamburger menu . I cant find whats wrong with the code.**

```
**This Is My HTML code**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to Sanan.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&family=Zilla+Slab+Highlight&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="leftNav">
```

**This is the sidebar**

```
            <div class="sideBar" id="sideBar">
```

**The below is the toggle button**

```
                <div class="toggleBtn" onclick="togglesideBar(this)">
                    <div class="lines"></div>
                    <div class="lines"></div>
                    <div class="lines"></div>
                </div>
                <ul id="navList">
                    <li id="item-1"><a href=""> Home</a></li>
                    <li id="item-2"><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li id="item-3"><a href="">Services</a></li>
                    <li id="item-4"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li id="item-5"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo1.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightNav">
            <input type="text" name="searchBox" id="searchBox" placeholder="Enter your search">
            <button id="search">Search</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**And When I created this section the side bar fades away and I cant click any buttons inside the sideBar**

```
    <section class="firstSection">
        <div class="mainBox">
            <h1> <span id="typed"></span> </h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam est aut molestiae minima aliquid voluptates amet iste? Optio suscipit quod, dolor provident dolore unde impedit possimus, sit aut dolorem quos?</p>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="sec-Btn">Browse Blog</button>
                <button class="sec-Btn">Browse Services</button>
                <button class="sec-Btn">Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.9/typed.min.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<-----CSS CODE---->
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

**I created a hamburger menu to collapse and open a side bar**

```
/* creating a hamburger */

.lines {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 3px;
}

.toggleBtn {
    position: relative;
    left: 235px;
    top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**All the properties I have set to the SideBar**

```
.sideBar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
```

**the class active is for side bar when i will click on the hamburger to open the sidebar I have toggled it with javascript**

```
#sideBar.active {
    left: 0px;
}

#navList li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

#navList li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#navList li a:hover {
    color: orange;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    /* border: 1px solid orange;
    padding: 2px 4px; */
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: black;
    /* border: 2px solid blue; */
}

.leftNav {
    width: 60%;
    /* border: 2px solid black; */
}

.rightNav {
    width: 40%;
    /* border: 2px solid black; */
}

.logo {
    /* border: 2px solid blueviolet; */
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px 60%;
}

.logo img {
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.rightNav {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

#searchBox {
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 4px 2px;
}

#search {
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
}

#search:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px white;
}
```

**the code for the Section comes here .This is the only section I have created after creating the navigation bar and the side bar**

```
/* Section-1 */

.firstSection {
    /* background: url('last.jpg')center center no-repeat; */
    /* background: white; */
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
}

.firstSection ::before {
    content: "";
    background: url('last.jpg')center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
}

.mainBox {
    /* border: 2px solid black; */
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

.mainBox h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-size: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.mainBox p {
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.buttons {
    max-width: 49%;
    /* border: 2px solid yred; */
    /* border: 2px solid red; */
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sec-Btn {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}

.sec-Btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px white;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```
<---JAVASCRIPT CODE--->
```

**This is the code to toggle classes of the side bar**

```
function togglesideBar(ref) {
    document.getElementById('sideBar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

**This code is for the animated heading inside my Section. I have used a javascript Typed.js library**

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("loaded")
    var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
        strings: ["Welcome to Sanan.com", "Learn Web Development", "Learn App development", "Learn Facebook Ads", "and other awesome programming concepts with me :)"],
        backSpeed: 15,
        smartBackspace: true,
        backDelay: 1200,
        startDelay: 1000,
        typeSpeed: 25,
        loop: true,
    });
}
```

```
*The image link is given below that will show you the exact problem im facing.
https://prnt.sc/114sdj0
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a CodePen or JSFiddle so everyone has a better overview of your files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to `.sideBar` something like below:

```
.sideBar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```